# Laptop frozen and cannot boot after trying to use a net stick

Tags: windows, freeze, boot

I have a laptop (LG X140) installed with Windows 7 starter. I use it for almost 2 years. Lately I have tried using a USB net stick. This caused the laptop to halt and since then I cannot boot. I get an error on boot. Trying to boot from external device (USB or DVD) with Windows 7 OS also freezes after the first screen showing that "Windows copies the files"
I will appreciate any help

Thanks
  Simon

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at your BIOS if there has something changed. Just try BIOS default values and look if works. Maybe your HDD isn't recognized correctly. So setting BIOS to default is maybe the best. Good luck.

Comment: I played with the BIOS settings with no success